# MSSQL Server Not Using NonClustered Composite Key Index (PK + FK) on InnerJoin

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Having the following structure:

```
Table Auction (Id_Auction (Pk), DateTime_Auction)
Table Auction_Item (Id_Auction_Item (Pk), Id_Auction (Fk), Id_Winning_Bid (Fk), Item_Description)
Table Bid (Id_Bid (Pk), Id_Auction_Item (Fk), Id_Bidder (Fk), Lowest_Value, Highest_Value)
Table Bidder (Id_Bidder (Pk), Name)
```

Indexes for Auction are not relevant.

Indexes for Auction_Item:

```
Clustered Index PK_Auction_Item (Id_Auction_Item)
NonClustered Index IX_Auction_Item_IdWinningBid (Id_Winning_Bid)
```

Indexes for Bid:

```
Clustered Index PK_Bid (Id_Bid)
NonClustered Index IX_Bid_IdBidder (Id_Bidder)
NonClustered Index IX_Bid_IdBid_IdBidder (Id_Bid, Id_Bidder) Unique Included (Id_Auction_Item, Lowest_Value, Highest_Value)
```

Indexes for Bidder are not relevant.

I'll ask you to bear with me a little... This structure is only to you recognize the relationship between the tables/data and is not intendent to be following best practices. The actual database is really more complex (Table "Bid" is like 54 millions rows). Oh, Yes, each Auction_Item will have only one "Bid per Bidder" with his highest and lowest bid.

So, when I execute the following query:

```
Select 
     Auc.Id_Auction,
     Itm.Id_Auction_Item,
     Itm.Item_Description,
     B.Id_Bid,
     B.Lowest_Value,
     B.Highest_Value

From
     Auction Auc
     Inner Join Auction_Item Itm on Itm.Id_Auction = Auc.Id_Auction
     Inner Join Bid B on B.Id_Bid = Itm.Id_Winning_Bid
                         And B.Id_Bidder = 27

Where Auc.DateTime_Auction > '2014-01-01';
```

Why Sql Server prefers to NOT use "IX_Bid_IdBid_IdBidder", and use this execution plan for **Bid**:

[image: Preferred execution plan]

If I disable IX_Bid_IdBidder, and force it to use "IX_Bid_IdBid_IdBidder" everything mess up:

[image]

I can't understand why MSSQL prefers use 2 indexes, instead of only one that covers completely the query. My only guess is that's faster to use the ClusteredIndex, but I can't believe that it's faster than just use the Unique Composite Key of the other NonClustered Index.

Why?

**Update:**
As proposed by @Arvo, I changed the order of key columns of the "IX_Bid_IdBid_IdBidder", making the Id_Bidder first and Id_Bid second. Then, it become the preferred index. So, once again, why is MSSQL using the less selective "Index Key", instead of the most selective key? The Id_Bid is explicitly related in the inner join...

**Old update:**
I Updated the query, making it even more selective.
Also, I updated the index "IX_Bid_IdBid_IdBidder", to include Id_Auction_Item

**Apologies:**
The Index IX_Bid_IdAuctionItem_IdBidder is in fact IX_Bid_IdBid_IdBidder, that INCLUDES Id_Bid IN THE INDEX UNIQUE KEY!

Comment: If you add Id_Bid column to IX_Bid_IdAuctionItem_IdBidder index, do things improve? Or make Id_Bidder first column in index?

Comment: @Arvo The Id_Bid already is added automatically, since it's the key of the clustered index and primary key. About the Id_Bidder be first in the key index, I cannot test it right now. But I'll do it latter and tell you the result, but I can say in advance that I can't see any advantage doing this. Making the seach for the PrimaryKey is the most selective condition, since there is only one Bid of One Bidder per Auction, but a Bidder can make Bids in several Auctions...

Comment: @Arvo My apologies, I already included Id_Bid in the index just like you said. In fact, I wrote my question wrongly, and corrected it right now...

Comment: @Arvo I inverted the order of columns in the Index Key, and now it's using it... But I still can't understand why it prefers to use the less selective, than the most selective...

Comment: Selectivity matters only when you limit your query results by condition for this field. Your query doesn't limit anything by Id_Bid - only limiting constraint is "B.Id_Bidder = 27".

Comment: @Arvo I also limit the query by DateTime_Auction. The problems is that I thought that MSSQL will start by limiting Auctions, then get Auctions_Items, and with the list of all Id_Winning_Bid from Auction_Item, get all Bids using the index IX_Bid_IdBid_IdBidder and FINALLY limiting by "Id_Bidder = 27". In this case, that index will work well, but this is not the best execution plan... Please, take a look to my self answer and let me know what do you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think that after a lot of research (and learn a bit more about how joins really work behind the scenes) I figured it out.

By now, I'll post it only as a theory, til some SQL Master say that it's wrong and show me the light, or I really be sure I'm right.

The point is that MSSQL is choosing what is fastest to the whole query, and not only to the Bid table. So the analyzer have to choose to start from Auction table, or Bid table (because the conditions I specified. DateTime_Auction, and Id_Bidder).
In my (frivolous) mind, I thought the best execution plan will be starting from the Auction table:

Get Auctions that match the specified date >> Get Auctions_Items matching inner join with Auctions >> Get the Bids matching inner join with Auction_Item AND that have Id_Bidder matching the specified id

This will select a lot of rows in each "level"/nested loop, and only in the end use the specified index to exclude 90% of data.

Instead, MSSQL want to start with the minimal data set as possible. In this case, only the Bids of the specified bidder, since there is a lot of Auction Items that the bidder could simply don't participate. Doing this, each nested loop have its outer table shrunken compared with "my plan".

Get Bids of specified bidder >> inner join with Auction_Item >> excludes Auctions matching date.

If you pay attention to the very most at right nested loop, that I presume is the first nested loop, the Outer table of the loop is the preselected list of Bids of a Bidder using the appropriate index (IX_Bid_IdBidder), than execute a scan on the clustered index, and etc...

To make it even better, I included the columns that was in the "IX_Bid_IdBid_IdBidder" into "IX_Bid_IdBidder", and MSSQL doesn't need to execute a Key lookup on the PK_Bid.

There is a lot of Auction Items to each Auction, but only one Bid from the specified Bidder for each Auction Item, so the first nested loop will select the minimum of valid Auction Items we will need, that also will limit the Auctions we will to consider matching the Date. Thus, since we are starting from Bids, there is not a "list" of Id_Bids to limit, and then MSSQL cannot use the index "IX_Bid_IdBid_IdBidder" EVEN it covering all the fields of query. Thinking now, it seems a little obvious.

Anyway, Thanks for everybody that helped me!

My research:
http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/advanced-join-techniques (a little outdated...)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191426%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191318%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/26/679319.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2009/03/18/optimized-nested-loops-joins.aspx

Answer (score 2):

A covering, correctly-sorted index is rarely not used by SQL Server. Only pathological cases come to mind such as extremely low page fullness or huge unneeded additional columns.

You index is simply not covering. Look at the columns that are output. You'll discover one that you have not indexed.

That column is `Id_Auction_Item`.

Comment: Please, take a look to my updated query... In fact, I don't even use the field Id_Auction_Item from the Bid table...
By the way, I added the field to Index, and don't make difference...

Comment: I think what you've shown still doesn't fit. The query seeks on Id_Product in the first image. But that column in not in the query. I'm giving up on this.

Comment: could you show me where did you see Id_Product in the first image?

Comment: Ow, sorry, I see now... Mistyping... Corrected now

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of people out there who know a lot more about SQL Server than I do, but this sounds a lot like one of two possible problems:

First it could be that SQL Server is using outdated statistics to determine what's "most efficient", and because the statistics are wrong, it's picking the wrong index.

The second is a lot less likely, but bears mentioning. You've not mentioned stored procedures in your text, but if this is in a stored proc, SQL could be using a cached (and very wrong) execution plan - look up 'parameter sniffing' for more explanation on this topic.

Comment: The first thing I thought was old statistics... So every time I change some index to test the suggested approaches, I execute a "Update Statistics Bid" call.
About the parameter sniffing, I'm executing it with hardcoded values, just like in the shown query, in my question.
Anyway, thanks for your time.